# Using requests with bs4 and or json

Tags: python, python-3.x, iframe, beautifulsoup

Here is the source of the of the page I am looking for. [Page Source](http://view-source:https://sports.bovada.lv//baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group). 
If page source is not working here is the link for the source only. "view-source:https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb"

Here is the Link: [Link to page](https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group)

I am not to familiar with using `bs4` but here is the script below which works, but does not return anything I need.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://sports.bovada.lv/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())
```

I can return the `soup` just fine. But what see from just inspecting the site and the returned `soup` are not the same.

Here is a sample of what I can see from inspect.
[image: inspect of page]

The goal is to remove the Team, pitcher, odds and total runs. Which I can clearly see in the inspect version. When I `print` `soup`that information does not come with.

Then I dove a little further and on the bottom of the Page source i can see an  iFrame and below that it looks like `json` dictionary with everything I am looking to extract but running a similar script to retrieve json data does not work like I had hoped:

```
import requests

req = requests.get('view-source:https://sports.bovada.lv//baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group')
data = req.json()['itemList']
print(data)
```

I believe i should be using `bs4` but I am confused on why the same `html` is not being returned.

Comment: This information is generated by a dynamic web page, i.e, the content is generated using Javascript and depends on the user's selections. If you parse the html you won't find the data, you'll find the Javascript code that generates the content. That doesn't mean that you cann´t access to the data, there are other ways, but probably you won't find it in the html source. You can see the tags with the inspector, but that is because the Inspector dynamically renders the source code. You could use the Inspector and analyze from where the data is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in json is dynamic which means it puts it into the HTML.

To access it with BS you need to access the `var` contained in the source which contains the json data. then load it into json and you can access it from there.

This is from the link you gave from `var swc_market_lists =`

So in the source it will look like

`<script type="text/javascript">var swc_market_lists = {"items":[{"description":"Game Lines","id":"136","link":"/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group","baseLink":"/baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-........`

now you can use the `swc_market_lists` in the `pattern` regular expression to only return that script.

Use `soup.find` to return just that section.

Because the `.text` will include the var part I have returned the data from the start of the json string.  In this case from `24` which is the first `{`

This means you now have a string of JSON data which you can then load as json and manipulate as required.

Hopefully you can work with this to find what you want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import json
from lxml import html
from pprint import pprint

import re


def get_data():

    url = 'https://sports.bovada.lv//baseball/mlb/game-lines-market-group'
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
    html_bytes = r.text
    soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'lxml')

    # res = soup.findAll('script') # find all scripts..

    pattern = re.compile(r"swc_market_lists\s+=\s+(\{.*?\})")
    script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

    return script.text[23:]

test1 = get_data()

json_data = json.loads(test1)

pprint(json_data['items'])
```

Comment: Wow, Im not totally sure whats going on with it but that gets me to the json data. Would it be possible to break down what your script is doing above a little more? Did you just search for `json-var`?

Comment: i first did `res = soup.findAll('script')`  to return only the scripts but you could search the source for `var` and put it into the pattern..